# Implementing social logins for customer in shopify store that I created from scratch using storefront API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I have a shopify store built in nextJs app that consumes shopify storefront APIs.
I want to enable social logins for the customers in my nextJs app but I dont seem to be able to find the right APIs to implement this.

currently, we're using shopify's username and password login for customers from storefront APIs.

I have searched through multiple sites and community but couldn't find help.

Comment: Is it Shopify plus? Most likely you will have to integrate using multipass api

Comment: thank you @TwistedOwl for response. NO, actually we can't afford shopify plus at the moment. are there shopify apps that provide me api for social login?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of, but very unlikely. On Shopify stores that can't use Multipass (meaning they are not Shopify Plus), there is a method of storing customers' credentials in the custom app that logins to Shopify if login to social media was successful but there are many security concerns regarding that. And plenty of development to glue everything together. I wouldn't recommend social login on Shopify Basic using either a custom app or a public app because there is a high risk of login data leakage. Multipass is the best choice in my opinion

Comment: There are of course more challenges -> e.g. keeping credentials in sync (people tend to reset and change their passwords)

Comment: okay, that carries a risk, the reason why I asked shopify app because I  came up with this shopify app [HIKO app](https://apps.shopify.com/simple-social-login) they are promising social login and in their paid plan they offering API's. could you please have a look and tell if I can use this app.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by API. They allow you to use your own auth server and that's it I guess. I don't want to recommend or discredit/harm any commercial vendor. From the developer's perspective, it's better to get rid of the responsibility (which is serious) of taking care of access to PII data (because of contractual penalties or compensation for damages)  but from a business perspective, it's better to stay away from 3rd party organizations that store your customer data or can access it. If they care of course (if they are selling in the EU they should).

Comment: If you are a developer you should be aware of limitations and risks and try to avoid recommending anything. It's not your responsibility to be a salesman/analyst. If you are a merchant/business person you should probably question if the risk of selling customers data or the cost of developing and maintaining a custom solution is worth the trouble.